# Trying to filter a list of dicts by the content of a nested list, but getting the same list of dicts back

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, filter

I have a list of dictionaries with the following stucture:

```
list_of_dicts = [
        {'id': 1, 'fruits':['apple']},
        {'id': 2, 'fruits':['orange']},
        {'id': 3, 'fruits':['banana', 'apple']},
        {'id': 4, 'fruits':['banana', 'apple', 'orange']}
        ]
```

I want to filter the `list_of_dicts` by the elements contained in the `'fruits'` keys. Specifically, I want to compare the fruits a list of acceptable fruits:

```
acceptable_fruits = ['apple', 'banana']
```

the expected result of this filter should be a list like this:

```
expected_result = [
        {'id': 1, 'fruits':['apple']},
        {'id': 3, 'fruits':['banana', 'apple']},
        {'id': 4, 'fruits':['banana', 'apple', 'orange']}]
```

I have attempted to nested filter statements, but that does not seem to work:

```
filtered_list = filter(lambda dict: filter(lambda fruit: fruit in acceptable_fruits, dict['fruits']), list_of_dicts)
```

The return in this case is the original list:

```
print(list(filtered_list))
```

returns:

```
[{'id': 1, 'fruits': ['apple']}, {'id': 2, 'fruits': ['orange']}, {'id': 3, 'fruits': ['banana', 'apple']}, {'id': 4, 'fruits': ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']}]
```

Other iterating loops have not worked well for me either. Does anybody have a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `filter` doesn't return a list in Python 3. Obviously, you're handling that for the outer filter with `list(filtered_list)`, but the inner `filter` is not handled, so it's evalutating as `True`, like this:

```
>>> f = filter(None, [])
>>> bool(f)
True
```

To fix it, you could just wrap the inner `filter` in `list()`, but really what you're trying to ask is "is any `fruit in acceptable_fruits`?", which is better written with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any). And besides, `list(filter(lambda))` is better written as a comprehension, for both inner *and* outer:

```
filtered_list = [
    d for d in list_of_dicts
    if any(fruit in acceptable_fruits for fruit in d['fruits'])]
```

Result:

```
[{'id': 1, 'fruits': ['apple']},
 {'id': 3, 'fruits': ['banana', 'apple']},
 {'id': 4, 'fruits': ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

can be easy with sets

```
list_of_dicts = [
        {'id': 1, 'fruits':{'apple'}},
        {'id': 2, 'fruits':{'orange'}},
        {'id': 3, 'fruits':{'banana', 'apple'}},
        {'id': 4, 'fruits':{'banana', 'apple', 'orange'}}
        ]
        
acceptable_fruits = {'apple', 'banana'}

result=[d for d in list_of_dicts if acceptable_fruits & d['fruits']]
print(result)
>>> [{'id': 1, 'fruits': {'apple'}}, {'id': 3, 'fruits': {'banana', 'apple'}}, {'id': 4, 'fruits': {'banana', 'apple', 'orange'}}]
```

Comment: `list_of_dicts` doesn't need to contain sets if you do `acceptable_fruits.intersection(d['fruits'])`.